# Vim 8 on 16.04.2 will not use system clipboard in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim, clipboard

But it works fine in an xterm.

I've completely apt removed all things vim and re-installed vim-gtk. I've confirmed that +clipboard and +xterm_clipboard are present. I've removed and re-installed the package repeatedly. I just built vim from the latest sources on github. I've cleared the mouse option (e.g. set mouse= ) and run vim without my config (-u NONE) to no avail.

setting clipboard=unnamed or clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus works fine in an xterm.

copying to the system clipboard via "*y works find in xterm.

Always the same result. xterm yes. gnome-terminal no.

I cannot figure it out. What am I missing?

EDIT: The title isn't totally accurate as it turns out. In my case, yanking within vim in a gnome-terminal does use the system clipboard. I can paste the contents into any other app. But if I *background* vim and then try to paste the contents into another app (including the terminal) it doesn't work. Again, works fine in xterm.

Comment: How did you try to access the clip board contents in vim?

Comment: Someone (or was it you?) just posted this the other day in Gnome's bugtracker at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=783828. We're investigating...

Answer (score 3):

Try installing `vim-gnome`. That's what made it work for me.